# Cannot find gridview EditItemTemplate in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I am trying to modify the content of a `TextBox` in the `OnRowEditing` event of the `gridview` but I cannot seem to find the `TextBox` control in code behind.

The field in aspx:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AssignTo" SortExpression="AssignTo">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAssignTo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AssignTo") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AssignTo") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Trying to find it in code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow grow = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
            TextBox txt = grow.FindControl("txtAssignTo") as TextBox;
        }
```

The `txt` variable is always null. Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind the `gridview` after you set the `editindex` (call its `DataBind()` method)

Comment: even if the data is coming from a sql data source?

Comment: Please set the datasource and bind grind just before the code TextBox txt = grow.FindControl("txtAssignTo") as TextBox;